# undefined method `first_name=' for #User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :login,
                  :password,
                  :email,
                  :first_name,
                  :middle_name,
                  :last_name,
                  :phone

 end
```

but, I have a problem =>

```
undefined method `first_name=' for #<User:0xa604c30>
...
test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
...
```

File with error
test/functional/users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @user = create :user
  end
...
```

FactoryGirl file
*test/factories/users/rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    login
    password
    first_name  "MyString"
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I may be missing something, why 2 negative votes already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error "undefined method `attribute=' for #" seems that you've forget migrate your database in Test Environment. Just run

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

As for me, first_name was new attribute in model, but I've forget migrate database in test environment.

Answer (score 2):

Try and update your test database with the latest migrations if you haven't done so already. The rake db:test:load recreates the test database from the current db/schema.rb.

```
rake db:test:load
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace in your file test/functional/users_controller_test.rb

the part

```
setup do
  @user = create :user
end
```

by

```
before { @user = create :user }
```

Or better:

```
let(:user) { create :user }
```

But if you choose this last technique, you must rename all `@user` by `user` in this file, and verify that your scenario are not using a `user` local variable. If this is not yet clear for you stick to the `before` technique.